# in console application i didn't get error but in windows form application i get an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

in console application i didn't get error but in windows form application i get an error 
i use the same script 
CONSOLE APPLICATION SCRIPT:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace FASERVERCMD
{
class Program
{
    public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        int counter = 0;

        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
        counter = 0;
        while ((true))
        {
            counter += 1;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;

            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

            clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

            broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
            handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
        {
            TcpClient broadcastSocket;
            broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.Value;
            NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

            if (flag == true)
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg);
            }
            else
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }

            broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
            broadcastStream.Flush();
        }
    }  //end broadcast function
}//end Main class


public class handleClinet
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    Hashtable clientsList;

    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)
    {
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        this.clientsList = cList;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }

    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }//end while
    }//end doChat
}
}
```

windows form application script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections;


namespace FARATSERVER
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStartserver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        int counter = 0;

        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
        counter = 0;
        while ((true))
        {
            counter += 1;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;

            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

            clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

            broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
            handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
        {
            TcpClient broadcastSocket;
            broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.Value;
            NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

            if (flag == true)
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg);
            }
            else
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }

            broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
            broadcastStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
public class handleClinet
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    Hashtable clientsList;

    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)
    {
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        this.clientsList = cList;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }

    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }//end while
    }//end doChat
}
}
```

Errors :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   CS0618  'TcpListener.TcpListener(int)' is obsolete: 'This
>   method has been deprecated. Please use TcpListener(IPAddress
>   localaddr, int port) instead.
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202' FARATSERVER D:\hacks\MVS\FARATSERVER\FARATSERVER\Form1.cs   27  Active
>   Warning   CS0162  Unreachable code
>   detected  FARATSERVER D:\hacks\MVS\FARATSERVER\FARATSERVER\Form1.cs   56  Active
>   Warning   CS0219  The variable 'serverResponse' is assigned but its value
>   is never
>   used  FARATSERVER D:\hacks\MVS\FARATSERVER\FARATSERVER\Form1.cs   105 Active
>   Warning   CS0219  The variable 'sendBytes' is assigned but its value is
>   never
>   used  FARATSERVER D:\hacks\MVS\FARATSERVER\FARATSERVER\Form1.cs   104 Active
>   Error CS0117  'Program' does not contain a definition for
>   'broadcast'   FARATSERVER D:\hacks\MVS\FARATSERVER\FARATSERVER\Form1.cs   121 Active

Answer (score 3):

The `broadcast` method no longer resides in the `Program` class. It is now inside the `Form1` class, so change the code on line 104 in the Winforms program from:

```
Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
```

to

```
Form1.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
```

(Code can be found in `handleClinet` => `doChat` => `while` => `try`)

---

Update based on advice from [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve):

Your "errors" are mostly warnings but only 1 is an error.

With warnings, your code compiles and works, but the compiler is "warning" you that something you did isn't really correct / should change if possible.

Error's really need to be fixed. So when you posted all your "errors" you actually posted only 1 error and 4 warnings.

Comment: While at it please advice him/her to understand the difference between a warning and an error message by the compiler

Comment: @fastaykoo if the code is working and my answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted. This indicates to the community that the answer is the correct one (if someone else has a similiar problem and comes across your question). See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information.